# Cant Get NeoComplCache in GVim on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have installed GVim on my Ubuntu computer and after adding necomplcache files to my vimfiles then adding let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1 to my .vimrc, I am still not getting popup autocompletion in gvim. I also tried to execute :NeoComplCacheEnable and get "Not an editor command".

I am new to using gvim on ubuntu and I did exactly the same thing in Windows and it works fine on Windows. I also tried AutoCompPop and couldnt get that to work in Ubuntu either.

Do these plugins work in Ubuntu GVim?

Are there other options for autocompletion in GVim in Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, there's Ctrl-n when in insert mode. Are you using something like [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)? It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my directory for plugins from vimfiles to .vim and it seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes. You should never touch `$VIMRUNTIME`. Your custom settings belong to `~/.vimrc` and your third party scripts belong to `~/.vim/`.